# Why can't my React Component find an element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Component that causes an error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null". It's nested inside of another component, and makes that component not load.

This is the code:

```
const NewItem = (props) => {

const qty = "QuantityBox" + props.identifier.toString();
const prc = "PriceBox" + props.identifier.toString();
return(
    <div className="NewItem">
        <div className="ItemNameInput">
            <p className="InputLabel">Item Name</p>
            <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div className="QuantityAndPrice">
            <div className="QuantityInput">
                <p className="InputLabel">Qty</p>
                <input className="inputEighth" value="1" id={qty} type="text" />
            </div>
            <div className="PriceInput">
                <p className="InputLabel">Price</p>
                <input className="inputFourth" value="0" id={prc} type="text" />
            </div>
            <div className="TotalOutput">
                <p className="InputLabel">Total</p>
                <h4 className="TotalAmount">{(document.getElementById(qty).value * document.getElementById(prc).value).toFixed(2)}</h4>
            </div>
            <img src={TrashCan} alt="Delete" />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Right in the "TotalAmount" h4, is where the problem arises. If I remove that part, it loads up just fine. Judging from the error, it can't find the elements I'm specifying, but I don't understand why. I don't know if it has anything to do with the parent component, but I'll put it here just in case:

```
class NewInvoice extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        numberOfItems: [0]
    };
}

createItem = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({numberOfItems: [...prevState.numberOfItems, (this.state.numberOfItems.length - 1)]}));
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="NewInvoice">
            <button onClick={() => this.props.goBackInvoiceList()} className="goBack">Go back</button>
            <h1>New Invoice</h1>
            <form>
                <p className="FormAreaLabel">Bill From</p>
                <div className="BillFrom">
                    <div className="StreetAddressInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Street Address</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="HalfInput">
                        <div className="CityInput">
                            <p className="InputLabel">City</p>
                            <input className="inputHalf" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="PostCodeInput">
                            <p className="InputLabel">Post Code</p>
                            <input className="inputHalf" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="NewCountryInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Country</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="BillTo">
                    <div className="ClientNameInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Client's Name</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="ClientEmailInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Client's Email</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="ClientStreetAddressInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Street Address</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="HalfInput">
                        <div className="ClientCityInput">
                            <p className="InputLabel">City</p>
                            <input className="inputHalf" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="ClientPostCodeInput">
                            <p className="InputLabel">Post Code</p>
                            <input className="inputHalf" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="ClientCountryInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Country</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="OtherInfo">
                    <div className="InvoiceDateInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Invoice Date</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="PaymentTermsInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Payment Terms</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="ProjectDescriptionInput">
                        <p className="InputLabel">Project Description</p>
                        <input className="inputFull" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3 className="ItemListTitle">Item List</h3>
                <div className="ItemList">
                    {this.state.numberOfItems.map((index) => 
                        <NewItem key={index} identifier={index} />
                    )}
                    <button onClick={() => this.createItem()} className="AddNewItem">+ Add New Item</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div className="NewInvoiceEndButtons">
                <button className="Discard">Discard</button>
                <button className="SaveAsDraft">Save As Draft</button>
                <button className="SaveAndSend">Save And Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because in the h4 line that you specified, you are trying to retrieve a DOM node with the id "QuantityBox" + props.identifier.toString(). Your code is unable to retrieve a DOM element with a matching id, causing document.getElementById(qty) to return null. null doesn't have any properties, so document.getElementById(qty).value is throwing an error specifiying that it cant access property value of null.
Also, if you want to manipulate DOM elements directly, the React way is to use React Refs. You should be able to achieve your desired result with that.

Read more on Refs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html